# HasMany associations update

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How to update `hasMany` associations in record?

I tried this approach:

```
record.get('childrenRecords').clear();
newChildrenRecords.forEach(function (child) {
  record.get('childrenRecords').pushObject(App.ChildModel.find(child.get('id'));
});
```

But I got error:

`Uncaught Error: <DS.ManyArrayStateManager:ember3557> could not respond to event recordWasAdded in state loading.`

Also I can't find right solution how to update `hasMany` associations in `Ember.data` docs.